# Can't get utf-8 upload file name in servlet on server wildfly 9.0.2

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, utf-8, wildfly-9

I want to upload image using servlet with server wildfy 9.0.2. But i can't get unicode utf-8 upload file name. I use code like below:

-upload.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <h1>File Upload</h1>
    <form method="post" action="UploadServlet"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select file to upload: <input type="file" name="file" size="60" /><br />
        <br /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

-UploadServlet.java

```
@WebServlet("/UploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*2, // 2MB 
                 maxFileSize=1024*1024*10,      // 10MB
                 maxRequestSize=1024*1024*50)   // 50MB
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Name of the directory where uploaded files will be saved, relative to
     * the web application directory.
     */
    private static final String SAVE_DIR = "uploadFiles";

    /**
     * handles file upload
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        // gets absolute path of the web application
        String appPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
        // constructs path of the directory to save uploaded file
        String savePath = appPath + File.separator + SAVE_DIR;

        // creates the save directory if it does not exists
        File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
        if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
            fileSaveDir.mkdir();
        }

        for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
            String fileName = extractFileName(part);
            System.out.println(fileName);
            part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
        }

        request.setAttribute("message", "Upload has been done successfully!");
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/message.jsp").forward(
                request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Extracts file name from HTTP header content-disposition
     */
    private String extractFileName(Part part) {
        String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
        String[] items = contentDisp.split(";");
        for (String s : items) {
            if (s.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                return s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length()-1);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

When i run project and upload image i get file name like below:

```
éåãå³ä»æ§å¤æ´ã®ãç¥ãã.png
```

Please help me !

Answer (score -1):

Issue seems to be in your servlet. You might have to look this code.
 //read uploaded file as a parameter
 `RequestParameter uploadedFile = request.getRequestParameter("file");`
 //read uploaded file in stream
 `InputStream fileStream = uploadedFile.getInputStream();`

This "fileStream" has file content. you could get it from this.
I hope, this will help you.

--
Jitendra

Comment: i will try as you said . but my code no problem when use in tomcat

Comment: Didn't understand your comment.

Comment: Sorry i mean that when i use my project with  tomcat server i can get unicode correct . but when i use with wildfly 9.0.2 server it have error as i shown above .